# How open modal pages conditionally?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am using Oracle APEX 21.1. I have a table `visits` with a column `visit_type`. visit_type has only values 1 or 2. There are 2 dialog pages(1 and 2). I need to create a query that returns a link that opens page 1 when visit_type = 1 and opens page 2 when visit_type = 2. Should I select a string with `<a href=""</a>` tag or use `APEX_PAGE.GET_URL` API. Either way, kindly, give me an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a typical format

```
  apex_string.format(
      '<a class="t-Button t-Button--hot t-Button--simple t-Button--stretch" href="%s">%s</a>'
    , apex_page.get_url
       (p_application => 'YOUR_APP'
       ,p_page        => t.visit_type
       ,p_items       => 'p'||t.visit_type||'_id'
       ,p_values      => t.visit_id
       )
    , 'Link text'
    ) as link_target
```

Don't forget to *not* escape special characters in your column definition.

Comment: I think ~apex_string.format~ is not mandatory, right? I tried **select 1 TEST, '<a href="' ||APEX_PAGE.GET_URL ( p_page => 2)|| '">Exam</a>' EXAM
from dual
union all
select 2 test, '<a href="' ||APEX_PAGE.GET_URL ( p_page => 5)|| '">Follow</a>' 
from dual;** and it works.

Comment: Can not I just select the link i.e select **<a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:3:&APP_SESSION.::NO:RP::"**? What is the difference?

Comment: Correct, I have it in my template for neatness, to help reduce quotes. You could build the entire URL with concatenation - no need for context switching to PL/SQL.

Comment: I don't recommend using &APP_SESSION. in your SQL. Use :APP_SESSION as a bind variable instead, it will benefit performance http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2012/02/apex-variables-in-sql.html

Comment: Aside question, with "context switching" what did you mean with "context" here? I often see this word and I don't know what it means, especially in JavaScript and jQuery. Does it have a special meaning in programming? Or is it just a generic word?

Comment: For example, https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aexjs/apex.html#.gPageContext$ and here, https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aexjs/actions.html#context

Comment: Context is used in a variety of scenarios in programming, but 'context switching' in relation to SQL specifically talks about the use of PL/SQL within your SQL - something to minimise. Steven Feuerstein talks about it a lot https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-cursors-context-switches-and-mistakes

Comment: When I tried **SELECT '<a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:5:&APP_SESSION.::NO:RP::">Open</a>' opens from dual;**, it showed **Invalid Character** error. After adding the domain name **SELECT '<a href="http://localhost:8080/ords/f?p=&APP_ID.:5:&APP_SESSION.::NO:RP::">Open</a>' opens from dual;**, The link is displayed. But when clicking it, it showed **No checksum was provided...** error. Why is error **No checksum provided** displayed when constituting the url as **f?p....** and not displayed when using **apex_page.get_url**?
2- What causes **Invalid character** error when not using the domain name?

Comment: I must correct myself. The apex_page.get_url would be required if your page has any form of state protection, since it will add the checksum when necessary. You probably won't see this behaviour if you remove the RP. Not sure about the invalid character, need more detail. What was the generated URL? Where was the error shown?